# Real numbers as limits of rationals

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I was reading Rudin's Principals of Mathematical Analysis. In an example on page 57 the author states:
Let $\{s_n\}$ be a sequence of all rationals, and if E is a set of all the sub-sequential limits then $E=R$ , where $R$ is the set of reals.

Though I remember from the calculus class that the square root of a natural number $S$ is the limit of the sub-sequence $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}\big(x_n+\frac{S}{x_n}\big)$ of the sequence of rationals if we pick $x_0\in \mathbb{Q}$

But I cannot see why is the set E=R, I mean how could we show something like this rigorously?

Comment: Do you mean that $E$ is __the__ set of all subsequential limits of the sequence?

Comment: Rudin basically states that each real! number can be approximated by a sequence of rational! numbers. Now, given an arbitrary real number $x$, can you find a sequence of rational numbers converging to $x$? (Hint: Decimal representation)
The recursive sequence you have given works great if $x$ is the square root of a natural number $S$ (why?), but what about other real numbers like $\pi$ or $e$?

Comment: @Frunobulax, thats exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose an arbitrary $r\in \mathbb R$ and let $R=\{r_n\}$ be a sequence of rationals which has the limit $r$ (I am assuming that you already know that such a sequence exists).

The sequence $S=\{s_n\}$ contains all rationals, so it contains every element of $R$ - but perhaps not in the same order. We need to find a correctly ordered subsequence which will therefore tend to $r$.

Let $n_1$ be the smallest integer for which $s_{n_1}=r_{m_1}\in R$. Then recursively define $n_i$ to be the smallest integer greater than $n_{i-1}$ for which both $s_{n_i}=r_{m_i}\in R$ and $m_i\gt m_{i-1}$. (check that this works - that there is always a number satisfying these conditions to be found)

Then the sequence $s_{n_i}$ is a subsequence of $S$, and the sequence $r_{m_i}$ is a subsequence of $R$, hence converges to $r$. The two sequences have been constructed to be identical, so $s_{n_i}\to r$ as required.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant point here is that $\mathbb Q$ is [*dense*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set) in $\mathbb R$, i.e. for each $x\in\mathbb R$ you can find a sequence $(a_n)$ of *rational* numbers with limit $x$.  You can even find such a sequence with the additional property that all the $a_n$ are different from each other.

Now, pick an arbitrary real $x$ and a sequence $(a_n)$ as above.  If you look at an initial segment $s_1,\dots,s_k$ of your sequence $(s_n)$ of *all* rational numbers, then only finitely many of the $a_n$ can be members of $\{s_1,\dots,s_k\}$.  As *all* rationals will eventually appear in $(s_n)$, [almost all](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_all) of the $a_n$ are yet to come.  Thus, $x$ is a subsequential limit of the sequence $(s_n)$.